# Check if a string contains any substrings from an array

Tags: ruby

I want to check if any elements in this array `words = ["foo", "bar", "spooky", "rick james"]` are substrings of the phrase `sentence = "something spooky this way comes"`.

Return true if there is any match, false if not.

My current solution (works but probably inefficient, I'm still learning Ruby):

```
is_there_a_substring = false
words.each do |word|
  if sentence.includes?(word)
    is_there_a_substring = true
    break
  end
end
return is_there_a_substring
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your solution is efficient, it's just not as expressive as Ruby allows you to be. Ruby provides the [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) method to express what you are doing with that loop:

```
words.any? { |word| sentence.include?(word) }
```

Comment: gotta love ruby... (will accept in 4 min when timer is up)

Comment: use `include?` as `includes?` doesn't work for me in ruby2.0

Comment: There is no `includes?` in Ruby. This answer needs to be edited to use `include?`

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a regular expression:

```
 if Regexp.union(words) =~ sentence
   # ...
 end
```